# Would it be faster to use server-side or client-side pagination/filtering/searching?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, angular

The current system that I am working on handles a variety of dataset sizes, most are around 100 but a handful of clients have 250,000 or more results. We need to handle a search across these results fields, pagination for varying page sizes up to 50, and filtering all results on a specific field.

Currently the server is setup to do all of these functions. Something to consider would be that a search would fire off a backend call, a column filter would fire off a backend call, etc. So lots of, most likely, faster calls to the backend.

The client could do these things on a cached large dataset, but it would probably be slower filtering/sorting when the dataset reaches the higher end of the spectrum.

Our primary considerations are speed and user experience. The backend approach would likely be faster & more frequent calls, but would cause lots of short load times and spinners for the user. The frontend would likely be a long initial load time and faster loads/data changes for the additional operations like filter/sort.

To those that have run into similar issues, what do you recommend? What were your concerns? Could you offer some good resources for this type of issue? Any and all assistance would be helpful.

PS sorry if this doesn't fit the standard code questions on SO, just looking for experienced help on this issue.

Comment: Usually returning EVERYTHING and filtering clientside is a really bad idea, it does not scale.

Answer (score 1):

in case of large date you have to use server side sorting, search and pagination

for performance you have to cache your http calls if you are calling the same endpoints within a given time period a couple of times.

you can find online many example of caching HTTP calls using RXJS, using handy operators like **shareReplay** that can cache and replay data for every subscriber and that makes you avoid making many calls to the server